# Attempting to create a Chatbot using IBM Watson Assistant and Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, ibm-cloud, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, watson-assistant

My friends and I are trying to **create a chatbot using IBM Watson Assistant and integrating it with Facebook Messenger as platform to host the chatbot.**

Our intention is to extract the **text** and **image data** that is inputted in the chatbot. Since the chatbot is integrated with Facebook, we are having problems finding a way to extract the data.

Any form of help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: Are you using the Facebook integration provided by Watson Assistant? If not, what are you doing? Share details.

Comment: Hi we are using the Facebook integration provided by Watson Assistant. The chatbot works fine, allowing the user to send text and picture as responses vice versa. However, we want to take it a step further to retrieve these texts and pictures and store them in a database for forwarding and future analysis. Any recommendations on how to do that? 

We are currently trying to link it up with IBM cloudant but with little success. We also explored to link it up via facebook, but the way we found so far requires the manual activation of web extensions and then downloading the data manually as PDF.

Comment: I see. Here on Stack Overflow you can ask programming question and you need to provide code samples of your work. I recommend joining thiis Slack workspace and asking there. It has many developers and users: http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/

Comment: Hi, if you are looking to only use the users input text for future analysis, and not store the data in real time, you may find it easier to pull the users input from the Watson logs. There is an Watson API that could be utilised to pull the logs and then store the data into Cloudant or another database. This could be done in a Cloud function with a trigger to run every hour, or day, pulling any new data from that time period.

Comment: @Ismail.Ishak you can attach a cloud function/webhook to node receiving user input  to store the input data in a cloud hosted database,